# How to add a condition for a reference in fluent nhibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

In my ClassMap I only want to load a property when it satifies a condition. This is the code I use now:

```
References<MyObject>(x => x.Property).ForeignKey("RecordId");
```

I'd like to add a Where clause to this: only load `x.Property` when a value in the database is zero, something like this:

```
References<User>(x => x.Property).ForeignKey("RecordId").Where("Removed = 0"); // Where Removed is a column of the user table
```

But this doesn't work unfortunately. Does someone knows an equivalent for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `ClassMap` class I've added a `Where` clause:

```
public class ClassAMap : ClassMap<ClassA>
{
    public ClassAMap()
    {
        Table("ClassA");

        // Only load Class A where the user is not removed
        Where("PersonRecId in (select u.Userid from Users u where u.Removed = 0)");

        Id(c => c.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();

        References<User>(x => x.User).ForeignKey("UserId");
    }
}
```

Note: You need to use aliases in the `Where` clause, otherwise it goes wrong.